# Update a table with count() from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

**Table test_a**

```
| genId | country | alcohol_spirits | music |
|-------|---------|-----------------|-------|
|     1 |      US |               0 |     0 |
|     2 |      IN |               0 |     0 |
|     3 |      SE |               0 |     0 |
```

**Table test_b**

```
| itemId |       headAlias | headDestinations |   iTitle |
|--------|-----------------|------------------|----------|
|      1 | alcohol-spirits |            US,SE | Bottle 1 |
|      2 | alcohol-spirits |            US,SE | Bottle 2 |
|      3 | alcohol-spirits |            US,SE | Bottle 3 |
|      4 | alcohol-spirits |               US | Bottle 4 |
```

**My sql**

```
update test_a set alcohol_spirits = alcohol_spirits + 
(
    select 
        count(itemId) 
    from test_b 
    where headAlias = 'alcohol-spirits' 
    and headDestinations IN ('US,SE') /* 'US,SE' = user input*/

) where country IN('US,SE') ; /* 'US,SE' = user input */
```

I'm trying to update table `test_a` with the `count()` of items from `test_b` for each country. It's hard to explain, but you'll see from my expected results.

For `alcohol_spirits`, the `US` has `4` and `SE` has `3`. I'm trying to update it all at once, but what I thought would work, does not. Where am I going wrong and how to get this right?

**Expected results**

```
| genId | country | alcohol_spirits | music |
|-------|---------|-----------------|-------|
|     1 |      US |               4 |     0 |
|     2 |      UK |               0 |     0 |
|     3 |      SE |               4 |     0 |
```

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET. (Although this really looks like a problem of poor design)

Comment: Your structure is quite fishy. Although you need to use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: @raheelshan I tried that too. If you know the right way, maybe you could post.

Comment: @Norman take a look at my answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use a query for this like this

```
UPDATE table_a a
SET a.alcohol_spirits = a.alcohol_spirits + 
(SELECT
     count(table_b.itemId)
 FROM table_b
 WHERE headAlias = 'alcohol-spirits' 
 AND country IN('US,SE')
 AND FIND_IN_SET(a.country, table_b.headdestinations)
)
```

Comment: You seem to have taken away the user input part `US,SE` and the `headAlias` in your solution.

Comment: Actually, the a.country part in your solution near find_in_set, comes from the user as ('US,'SE'). However, when I put that in there, it won't work. Any way that can be done?

Comment: If the user input is ('US, SE) only data for those two countries needs to be selected. Not all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
update test_a set 
alcohol_spirits=(
select alcohol_spirits+count(*) from test_b where headDestinations like '%'+country +'%')
```

this query will added current alcohol_spirits with every execution you shout alwase update with only count like following query

```
update test_a set 
alcohol_spirits=(
select count(*) from test_b where headDestinations like '%'+country +'%')
```