# Storing item totals for 30 categories across 20 countries

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I need to store the totals for items in 30 categories across 20 countries (initially), and also be able to easily update and retrieve them. What would be a good way to do this?

My current method is to use the categories as column names.

```
"genId" "country"   "alcohol_spirits"   "music" /* other categories go here */
"1"     "US"        "0"                 "0"
"2"     "UK"        "0"                 "0"
"3"     "SE"        "0"                 "0"
/* other countries go here */
```

**or**

Use the country codes as column name

```
 "genId"    "category"      "US"    "UK" /* other countries go here */
    "1"     "music"         "0"     "0"
    "2"     "movies"        "0"     "0"
    "3"     "food&Beverage" "0"     "0"
    /* other categories go here */
```

No ones got anything good to say to both of my approaches.

Can you suggest a better way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update a table with count() from another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807781/update-a-table-with-count-from-another-table)

Comment: @Strawberry How is this a duplicate?

Comment: You have correctly come to the realisation that your schema is in need of a redesign. With that in mind, it is inappropriate to ask the SO community to continue to consider a problem associated with a schema which is no longer relevant. You should close that question. Or amend it and close this one.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a table for category with a category ID and its description and another table for the countries. Then you in your main table (whatever it is) you can link to both using the IDs instead.

Also, you have me worried when you say you want to store totals. Are you planning on storing calculated values ? This is a big no-no in database design. You should always recalculate everything everytime *except* when it has a time-cost that is unacceptable.

Comment: That's right. I plan on counting the totals and storing them. The totals will be displayed next to each category in the menu. So that way I won't have to do count each time the menus needs to be displayed on page load.

Comment: That's a terrible design choice. Unless you have a lot of data (30 categories for 20 countries is (and by far) not a lot), storing calculations in a table risks making your data inaccurate or downright wrong. There is no need to optimize something if it is not a bottleneck and degrades data quality.

Answer (score 1):

Well, from your design, it seems when the category or country grows, you have to change your table structure. In many environment, it causes troubles.

I probably will have table as follow,

Table Country

country ID

....

Table Category

Catetory ID

.....

Table Totals

CountryID

CategoryID

TotalValue

....